# Pass local HTML file to ChatGPT API and ask multiple questions

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

This code works:

```
import os
import openai
import requests

openai.organization = "<MYORG>"
openai.api_key = "<MYAPIKEY>"
openai.Model.list()

url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
payload = '{"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo","messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Say this is a test!"}],"temperature": 0.7}'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer <MYAPIKEY>'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

However, what I really want is to pass a local HTML file (saved from [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09BMSNYV4) to my disk) and ask multiple questions (also to reduce API calls) like:

1. get me an array of the product images
2. what is the price of the product?
3. get me the brandname of the product
4. get me the URL of the first video under "Videos for related products"
5. get me the product description

How would I do that?